# React-native TouchableOpacity effect on Text

Tags: react-native

I want my Text component to have the same effect that TouchableOpacity does on touch. Is there anyway to make that happen with the Stylesheet or props? I could have onPress make the opacity go down, but that doesn't have the opacity go back up.

Comment: If you put your text inside TouchableOpacity doesn't that get you this effect?  `<TouchableOpacity><Text></Text></TouchableOpacity>`

Comment: So i'm using flexWrap: 'wrap' on my text component so the text doesn't go off screen and if I wrap it in View or TouchableOpacity that stops working.

Comment: I think your real question is "How to flex wrap text within TouchableOpactiy?" There are threads on that.

Answer (score 0):

You want like this?

```
renderButton: function() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Image
        style={styles.button}
        source={require('./myButton.png')}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should surround your `Text` tag with `TouchableOpacity` they will work together

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
    Your text
  <Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

then you can change `() => console.log('pressed')` with anything you want.

Also, you are able to use [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight) for styling, please check the documentation.